# ball bouncing off the floor

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

there is a ball falling with the speed of free fall. I can't write logic that makes the ball hit the surface and bounce.
I would like physics to be close to real

Please help to solve the problem. thank you in advance)

below is the code;)

```js
window.onload = () => {
const out = document.getElementById('out') 
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
let metr = 0.1;
let seconds = 1000;

let speed = 9.8;
const vector = { x: 0, y: 1}
const position = {x: 300, y: 0}
function draw(timeDelta) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600)
  const dX = (vector.x * (metr * (timeDelta / seconds) * speed) || 0)
  const dY = (vector.y * (metr * (timeDelta / seconds) * speed) || 0)
  
  position.x += dX
  position.y += dY

  out.innerText = `${position.x}, ${position.y}, ${dX}, ${dY}`

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(position.x, position.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.moveTo(0, 550);
  ctx.lineTo(600, 550);
  ctx.stroke();
   
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

draw();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background: gray
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="out">Out</div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you gave up coding after you got the ball to drop.  Where is your code to detect the ball hitting the floor?  Code to "bounce" the the ball back up?  What algorythm are you going to use to simulate gravity?  What have you attempted?  Please [edit] your question to address this.

Comment: Have a look at the [matter.js physics engine](https://brm.io/matter-js/index.html). It's really powerful and well-suited for this task.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dropBall = new janvas.Canvas({
  container: "#app",
  interval: 16, // animation loop interval
  props: {
    background: void (0),
    ball: void (0) // target object
  },
  methods: {
    init: function () {
      this.background = new janvas.Rect(this.$ctx, 0, 0); // init background
      this.background.getStyle().setFillStyle("white").setLineWidth(10); // set style
      this.ball = new janvas.Arc(this.$ctx, 0, 50, 50); // init target ball
      this.ball.vy = 0; // velocity y
      this.ball.g = 1; // acceleration
      this.$raf.start(); // start the default animation with requestAnimationFrame
    },
    update: function () {
      this.ball.vy += this.ball.g; // every loop velocity += acceleration
      this.ball.setStartY(this.ball.getStartY() + this.ball.vy); // set ball position
      if (this.ball.getStartY() + this.ball.getRadius() > this.$height) {
        this.ball.setStartY(this.$height - this.ball.getRadius());
        this.ball.vy *= -1; // if ball touch the bottom, inverse velocity y
      }
      this.onPositionChange(this.ball.getStartX(), this.ball.getStartY()); // position callback
    },
    draw: function () {
      this.background.fillStroke(); // draw the background and stroke
      this.ball.fill(); // draw the ball
    }
  },
  events: {
    resize: function () { // change some props on resize
      this.ball.setStartX(this.$width / 2);
      this.background.setWidth(this.$width).setHeight(this.$height);
    },
    onPositionChange: janvas.Utils.noop
  }
});
var p = document.querySelector("p");
dropBall.onPositionChange = function (x, y) {
  p.innerHTML = x + "," + y;
};
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/janvas/dist/janvas.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div id="app" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: It would be good if you could explain the calculation also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the collision detection code from a small physics sim I setup a while back.

Where your world seems to consist of a single circle or sphere and a single plane, I had many particles in addition to walls and a ceiling. All 4 of my planes are axis-aligned and exist 0.75 units from the origin.

The particles each hold a little info about themselves, as do the planes I used for the bounding box.

```
class particle
{
    constructor( pos=new vec2d(0,0), vel=new vec2d(0), restCoef=1 )
    {
        this.mPos = vec2d.clone(pos);
        this.mVel = vec2d.clone(vel);
        this.mCoefRest = restCoef;
    }
    get pos(){return this.mPos}
    set pos(newPos){this.mPos.setTo(newPos)}
    get vel(){return this.mVel}
    set pos(newVel){this.mVel.setTo(newVel)}
    get restCoef(){return this.mCoefRest;}
    set restCoef(newCoef){this.mCoefRest = newCoef;}
};

class plane
{
    constructor(normalX, normalY, distToOrigin)
    {
        this.mNormal = new vec2d(normalX,normalY);
        this.mDist = distToOrigin;
    }
    get dist(){return this.mDist;}
    set dist(newDist){this.mDist = newDist;}
    get normal(){return this.mNormal;}
    set normal(newNormal){this.mNormal.setTo(newNormal);}
}
```

The update-loop is entirely trivial, drawing moving & colliding each frame.

```
function update2()
{
    drawParts(partArray);
    move(partArray, 1/60);
    handleCollisions2(partArray);
    requestAnimationFrame(update2);
}
```

I suppose all the stuff you'll find interesting lives in the code to both move and collide the particles.

```
function move(parts, timeStep)  // array, seconds
{
    parts.forEach(
        function(part)
        {
            var grav = new vec2d(0,-9.8);
            grav.timesEquals(1/60);     // should be timeStep, not 1/60 (I had timeStep = 1/60)                                                                                 
            part.vel.plusEquals(grav);
            var dist = part.vel.clone();
            dist.timesEquals(timeStep);
            part.pos.plusEquals(dist);
            part.vel.timesEquals(0.99);
        }
    )
}
```

You can see that I never got around to implementing all my ideas. I never even touch the planes input here, instead making up a bounding-box as I go..

```
function handleCollisions2(parts, planes)
{
    var planeArray=[];
    planeArray.push( new plane(1,  0, 0.75) );
    planeArray.push( new plane(0, -1, 0.75) );
    planeArray.push( new plane(-1, 0, 0.75) );
    planeArray.push( new plane(0,  1, 0.75) );
    partArray.forEach(
        function(part,idx)
        {
            planeArray.forEach(
                function(plane)
                {
                    var N = plane.normal;
                    var dist = part.pos.dotProd(plane.normal) + plane.dist;
                    var dp = part.vel.dotProd(N);
                    if (dist<0 && dp < 0)   // wrong side of plane and penetrating further (not moving away)
                    {
                      // collision response, reflect particle
                      var nDotV = vec2d.clone(plane.normal);
                      //nDotV.timesEquals(2);
                      nDotV.timesEquals(1+part.restCoef);
                      nDotV.timesEquals(dp);
                      
                      part.vel.minusEquals(nDotV);
                      
                      var tmpN = plane.normal.clone();
                      part.pos.minusEquals( tmpN.timesEquals(dist) );
                      //V[i] -= 2*N*N•V[i];
                      //console.log('.');   
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```js
window.onload = () => {
const out = document.getElementById('out') 
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var dpi = (document.getElementById('dpi').offsetWidth * 2.54)
const m = 1 / dpi;

const w = 600, h = 600, r = 5;
const box = [10, 10, h - 10, w - 10]

const g = 9.8 * m;
const speed = { x: -1350 * m, y: -560 * m }
const friction = 0.95
const position = {x: (box[2] - box[0]) / 2, y: (box[2] - box[0]) / 2 }

let i = 0;
function draw(timeDelta) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600)
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  
  speed.y += (g * m * timeDelta) || 0
  // speed.x += (m * timeDelta) || 0
  
  position.y = Math.max(box[1] + r, Math.min(box[3] - r, position.y + speed.y));
  position.x = Math.max(box[0] + r, Math.min(box[2] - r, position.x + speed.x));
  
  if (position.y + r >= box[3] || position.y - r <= box[1]) {
    speed.y = -(speed.y * friction)
    speed.x = speed.x * friction
  }
  
  if (position.x + r >= box[2] || position.x - r <= box[0]) {
    out.innerText = ++i
    speed.y = speed.y * friction
    speed.x = -(speed.x * friction)
  }

  //out.innerText = `${Math.round(position.y)}, ${Math.round(position.x)}, ${Math.round(speed.y * 1000) / 1000}, ${Math.round(speed.x * 1000) / 1000}`

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(position.x, position.y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.moveTo(box[0], box[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(box[2], box[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(box[2], box[3]);
  ctx.lineTo(box[0], box[3]);
  ctx.lineTo(box[0], box[1]);
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.stroke();
   
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

draw();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background: gray
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="out">Out</div>
  <div id="dpi" style="height: 1in; width: 1in; left: 100%; position: fixed; top: 100%;pointer-events:none"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```